# How to learn Latin without resources in mother language

Tags: classical-latin, pedagogy

My native language is Persian. There's no good and comprehensive book in Persian for learning Latin and Ancient Greek.
There is no tradition for teaching these classical languages in Iran. Also in the universities we do not have European classical studies.
Although there are some mid-range books in Persian for some Old IE languages like Sanskrit.
My English level is intermediate and for learning a new language I cannot fully rely on English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common problem.
If, for example, a speaker of a small European language wants to learn a small African language, chances are that there is no material for that pair of languages.
To be useful to a broad readership, I will write without reference to Persian; I have next to zero knowledge of Persian and especially learning Latin from it, so I could not give specific advice anyway.

I suggest using a mixture of methods when the resources in your native language are limited:

1. If there are any resources in your native language or any language you feel comfortable enough with, start with them.
   They might be lacking in quality or they might not go very far or they might focus on an aspect you are less interested in, but they provide a low-threshold way to get started.
2. Take a look at the book series *Lingua Latina per se illustrata* (The Latin language illustrated through itself) by Hans Ørberg.
   It is material about Latin written in Latin.
   There are supporting books in English, but the bulk of it is in Latin.
   I have heard excellent things about these books but I have never used them myself.
   The material is excellent but probably not good for your first material; that's why I recommend getting some basics in another way.
3. Learn through an intermediate language.
   While you may not feel strong enough with English, your command of the English language seems perfectly sufficient for using it to learn Latin.
   A good choice of an intermediate language between your own and Latin depends on your situation.
   English is a good guess, but certainly not the only one.
   There is a lot of material in English, including a Duolingo Latin course.
4. Ask questions on this site when you don't understand something.
   You will be confused at times when learning a new language, and it is important to have a method for clearing those confusions.
   Asking here is a good way.
   Just write up a question and explain what you are struggling to understand and what your current understanding is.
5. Don't be afraid to switch methods.
   What helps you get started (e.g. material in your native language or the Duolingo course) might not work in the long run.
   You'll only find out what works for you by trying things out.